# Xcode 4: Add Build Phase After Run?

Tags: xcode

Is is possible to run a shell script after the build and run of a target?

I don't care about the exit code of the execution just that the script is run every time after execution.

Answer (score 1):

### **after run**

modify the scheme for running and add a post-action script

- click on the scheme in the upper left popup.
- select edit scheme
- expand the selected entry in the listview that pops up. (Called Run XY)
- click on Post-Actions
- and there click the + button
- now select add new run script.

### **after build**

as last phase of the build :)

- got to your project
- there click on build phases
- and there click the + button
- now select add new script phase.

=> drag and drop the box for this new build phase to where in the process you want it. **in your case, drag it to the bottom of the list, below copy bundle resources**